# AWS - Security groups reports powershell

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to pull several region such as us-west-1, us-west-2 or everything security groups from aws but it doesn't seem to be working and it is getting the region that was defined in ./config

is there a way to pull it from all region? and how should i do it?

that is what i have done so far.

```
Import-Module AWSPowershell


>     $EC2GroupList =  Get-EC2SecurityGroup | Select-Object Description, GroupId, GroupName, 
>     IpPermission, IpPermissionsEgress, VpcId 
>        
>     $ChangeList = @()
>            
>         $GroupsCount = ($EC2GroupList | Measure-Object).Count
>         foreach($SecGroup in $EC2GroupList) {
>             $Description = $SecGroup.IpPermission.Ipv4Ranges.Description
>             $GroupID = $SecGroup.GroupId
>             $SecurityGroupName = $SecGroup.GroupName
>             $SourceIP = $SecGroup.IpPermission.Ipv4Ranges.CidrIp
>             $FromPort = $SecGroup.IpPermission.FromPort
>             $ToPort = $SecGroup.IpPermission.ToPort
>             $Protocol = $SecGroup.IpPermission.IpProtocol
>             
>             echo $GroupsCount
>     
>         if($FromPort -ne $null) {
>         $NewObject = new-object -TypeName PSobject
>         #$NewObject | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name Region -Value
>         $NewObject | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name Description -Value $Description
>         $NewObject | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name GroupID -Value $GroupID
>         $NewObject | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name SecurityGroupName -Value $SecurityGroupName
>         $NewObject | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name SourceIP -Value $SourceIP
>         $NewObject | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name FromPort -Value $FromPort
>         $NewObject | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name ToPort -Value $ToPort
>         $NewObject | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name Protocol -Value $Protocol
>         $ChangeList += $NewObject 
>         } 
>     }
>     
>       echo $ChangeList
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API calls are mostly region specific except for a few global services so you need make a call per region generally. You can override the region like this: `Get-EC2SecurityGroup -region eu-west-2`.

Heres a rough sample

```
# wrap up your existing code in a function for later...
function Get-RegionSecurityGroupReport{
    Param([String] $region = 'eu-west-1');

    # replace with your code but pass $region when calling any APIs e.g.
    $EC2GroupList = Get-EC2SecurityGroup -region $region | Select-Object ...


    # return current regions data
    return $EC2GroupList;
}

# Setup the script
$activeRegions = @('eu-west-1', 'eu-west-2');
$results = @();


# loop through regions and execute your function with each region in turn...
$activeRegions | % {
   Write-Host "Processing region $($_)";
   $results += Get-RegionSecurityGroupReport -region $_;
}
# your multi regional report:
Write-Host $results
```

Comment: i was able to pull all groups from all regions but now i would to add a custom report with the ipPermission but i'm still get and getting the wrong output

Comment: @dave-ng77 it sounds like you have a different question and have made a number of changes to your code so it will be very difficult to help you. Please mark this question answered and then open a new question about the ipPermission issue (include your updated code, and describe what your trying to do and what exactly is the problem/error).

Answer (score 0):

There is an API call [DescribeRegions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeRegions.html) gets you all the regions available and the corresponding aws cli call [describe-regions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-regions.html).

I found this blog post [aws-regions-and-windows-powershell](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/aws-regions-and-windows-powershell/) and the corresponding call [Get-EC2Region](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Get-EC2Region.html).